# How do you pass a photo taken from a UIImagePickerController to a new view without using a segue (Swift 1.2)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 2 ViewControllers. My main `ViewController` and another called `decisionController`.

In `ViewController`, I have a button that opens a `UIImagePickerController` to a photo camera, user can take a photo, resize(edit) it and then tap "Use Photo". The original image and edited image are stored into two separate variables. The picker is then dismissed. The `decisionController` is then presented and I use the function defined in `decisionController` to pass the images into `decisionController`.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    var mediaDictionary : NSDictionary = info as NSDictionary

    var pickerMedia : String = mediaDictionary.objectForKey("UIImagePickerControllerMediaType") as! String

    if (pickerMedia == "public.image"){

        /////// Store the original image
        var oldImage : UIImage = mediaDictionary.objectForKey("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage") as! UIImage

        ///////// Store the edited image
        var newImage : UIImage = mediaDictionary.objectForKey("UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage") as! UIImage

        ///////// Dismiss the UIImagePickerController
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        ///////// Define my decisionController as svc
        var svc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("decisionController") as! decisionController

        ///////// Present decisionController
        self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        ///////// Call the setImages function from decisionController
        svc.setImages(oldImage, newImage: newImage)

    }
```

In `decisionController`, I have two `UIImageViews`, each has an `IBOutlet` that references the `oldImage` and `newImage`, respectively.

```
    class decisionController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var originalImageView : UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var editedImageView : UIImageView?

    func setImages(oldImage : UIImage, newImage : UIImage)
    {
        originalImageView?.image = oldImage
        editedImageView?.image = newImage

    }
        override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    }
```

EDIT: So when I run this I get the new ViewController to display but it doesn't show my photos captured because it doesn't seem to be passing them. I've put some breakpoints in the both views and my UIImageViews have a value of `nil`

EDIT2: My problem is that when I normally pass a variable from one view to another, I have a segue involved and I use that to pass the variable but in my case I am opening up the UIImagePickerController and when the user taps "Use Photo" there's no segue involved in my storyboard  so I can't use the same method I'm am accustomed which is using the prepareforsegue method by creating a segue between the two views, giving the segue an identifier in my storyboard and referencing that in the prepareforsegue. I solved my problem by adding this after I define `svc` in my `ViewController`

`svc.image1 = oldImage`
`svc.image2 = newImage`

Then adding this in decisionController before viewDidLoad

`var image1 : UIImage = UIImage()`
`var image2 : UIImage = UIImage()`

And adding this in viewDidLoad

`orignalImage.image = image1`
`editedImage.image = image2`

So now, when I run it, it defines `svc` and I tell it that the 2 variables in `svc` that I created (`image1` and `image2`) should hold `oldImage` and `newImage`, respectively, which are the original photo taken and resized one. Then it presents the view, the view loads and it takes the `image1` and `image2` variables holding the photos and sets them to the `image` value of each `UIImageView`, respectively.

No segue was needed, and my problem is solved.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I've updated my original question. My issue is that it doesn't seem like the photos are being passed to my decisionController from the ViewController because the values of the UIImageViews are nil and after the UIImagePickerController is dismissed I get a white View where the UIImageViews should be.

Comment: `svc.setImages(oldImage, newImage: newImage)` should be called before `self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)` I guess

Comment: @iRealMe That didn't produce any different results.

Comment: @matt I've updated my question and code. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setImages` function is calling properly but it does not update the image views because `decisionController`'s view has not been loaded yet. Two ways you can solve this problem.

**Try 1:** Simply by calling `setImages' in completion may solve this problem

```
    self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        svc.setImages(oldImage, newImage: newImage)
    }
```

**Try 2:** You can try this one which is best practice. Create two variable which will retain the original and edited image and set images from viewDidLoad function.

Add two variables to `decisionController' class

```
var originalImage : UIImage?
var editedImage : UIImage?
```

And then set images after picking from image picker

```
    ///////// Call the setImages function from decisionController
    svc.setOriginalImage(oldImage)
    svc.setEditedImage(newImage)
```

Now call `setImages` method from `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    setImages(orginalImage!, newImage: editedImage!);
}
```

Comment: Your second suggestion gave me an idea and I managed to do it without the segue like I wanted and without using the `setImages` function that I created. See my question edit2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the time you call `setImages` the decision controller's view and outlets are not loaded yet. So the image views are nil and nothing happens.

Comment: So how can I set the images after the view has been loaded?

Comment: You can't. Well, maybe you can, but you shouldn't. You have no business trying to reach into one view controller's interface from another view controller. Instead, give the decision controller two UIImage properties. You can set those. Now the decision controller in its `viewDidLoad` can grab those images and put them into its own image views. `viewDidLoad` means (get this) that the view _has_ loaded, so this will work, and it means that everyone is doing his own job properly.

Comment: Hi matt, what exactly do you mean when you say "give decision controller two UIImage properties"?

Comment: @Junior please see my answer. I hope you will find something very clear and will solve your problem.